# Not Able To Get Intent Extra Text In Second Time When App In Background Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I using This code to start my activity with Intent Extra Text and at first time it work fine but when i again sharing a text with my app then it just launch my app but not extra text showing at all. can anybody help me

Note: doing some modification in coding it showing same intent extra text again again.

Here is MainActiviy Code

```
     protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)        {

     Intent intent = Intent;
        string action = intent.Action;          
        string type = intent.Type;           
        if (Intent.ActionSend.Equals(action) && type != null)
        {
           // intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            if ("text/plain".Equals(type))
            {
                handleSendText(intent); // Handle text being sent
            }
        }
          }

     public void handleSendText(Intent intent)
    {         
        string sharedText = intent.GetStringExtra(Intent.ExtraText);            
        if (sharedText != null)
        {              
          Toast.MakeText(this, sharedText, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
    }
```

And AndroidManifest.Xml

```
     <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Everything Working Fine But The Problem Is At Second Time When App In Background And I Go To Other App And Sharing Any Text With My App It Just Open My MainActiviy Without New Intent Extra Text Or Same Intent Extra Text. Please Help Me to Sort This Out.

Answer (score 0):

It's because OnCreate() is only called the first time the activity is loaded.  You should move your Intent detection code to OnResume() as that's called every time the activity comes to the foreground.

Here's a simplified working example:

**MainActivity.cs**

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.main_layout);
    var btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnLoadSenderActivity);
    btn.Click += (sender, e) => { StartActivity(typeof(SenderActivity)); };
}

protected override void OnResume() {
    base.OnResume();
    Intent intent = Intent;
    string sharedText = intent.GetStringExtra("KEY");
    if (sharedText != null) Toast.MakeText(this, sharedText, ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
```

**SenderActivity.cs**

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.sender_layout);
    var btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnSendIntent);
    btn.Click += (sender, e) => {
        var value = $"Current Date/Time is {DateTime.Now}";
        Intent i = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        i.PutExtra("KEY", value);
        StartActivity(i);
    };

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you sir but this don't help me.. this only returning same value giving in SenderActivity. When I Try Share A Link MainActivity Opening But Intent Don't Show.  Please there is any way to solve this.

Comment: I updated the answer to now pass the current date and time to show that the value is changed with subsequent calls.  It works for me.  I would try using my code as a starting base and then slowly add in any code needed for your requirements until you find out what is causing the issue.  Let me know what you find out!

Comment: Again Thank You For Reply, Sir I Think My Question You Take Wrong Way I'm Sorry For My English. I Am Trying To Make An App Which Take Input Or Like Url From Other Apps And It Show Inside My App. Something LIke Below Image I Using My App And Only First Time It Work Fine But At Second Time My Activity Launch As You Said Cause OnCreate Call Only First Time. That Is My Problem Second Time When I again Sharing Url Or Text It Just Open My Activity No Update For Intent Extra.[https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/ionicframework/original/3X/e/7/e7d94fbd83827666d2f50926b667b4cc834097da.png]

Comment: @dean The resource has denied. You could make it in a butto event wuthout using it directly in OnCreate.